# How do I add an auto_ptr to a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I've been attempting to solve this problem for hours, because I can't get a pointer to delete itself so I created a text-based program for debugging. Why doesn't this work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A {};

int main() {
    vector<A> as;
    std::auto_ptr<A> a(new A);
    as.push_back(std::move(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do exactly what you're doing now, but use unique_ptr instead of auto_ptr.

Comment: Don't use `std::auto_ptr` use `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: @immibis it says "no matching function for call to 'std::vector<A>::push_back(std::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<A>&>::type)'"

Comment: You are trying to put a smart pointer into a vector full of `A`s. Declare your vector to take `std::unique_ptr<A>` rather than just `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the vector contains `A` objects, you want `as.push_back(*a)`. You don't need `std::move`, the temporary `*a` is already moveable.